# Need to show Subcategory's Description in magento

Tags: php, magento

I've a problem to get subcategory description on the below code.

```
  $category_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');  
    $_category = $category_model->load(3); //loaded one category
    $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories(); 

     foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): 
      echo $_subcategory->getName(); 
      echo $_subcategory->getDescription(); //I can't able to get description of the subcategory
     endforeach;
```

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution and i added answer to my question. Much optimized answer will also be appreciated. Thanks.

```
$category_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');  
    $_category = $category_model->load(3); //loaded one category
    $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories(); 

     foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): 
      echo $_subcategory->getName(); 
     //echo $_subcategory->getDescription(); //I can't able to get description of the subcategory
    //Added to make as current category
      $cur_category=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_subcategory->getId());
      $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
      $layer->setCurrentCategory($cur_category);
      echo $this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription();

 endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what your trying to do, but try

```
$category_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');  
$_category = $category_model->load(3); //loaded one category
$_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories(); 

foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): 
    $cur_category=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_subcategory->getId());
    echo $cur_category->getName();
    echo $cur_category->getDescription();
endforeach;
```